# Opacity in ThreeJS without set opacity on material

Tags: three.js, blender

I'd like to set the opacity of a mesh I have imported from blender.

```
var weapons = imported_scene.getObjectByName("weapons");
weapons.material.opacity = 0.5;
weapons.material.transparent = true;
```

Problem: The material of this mesh is in use for another mesh too and therefore the other mesh gets the opacity as well.

Reason: I have a scene (with two meshes) created in Blender. The exported JSON will be imported with the ObjectLoader. Both meshes uses for performance reasons the same texture file.

Is there any way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to make two materials in order to have one be transparent and the other not, but you can do this without loading the same texture file twice. The easiest way would be cloning the material:

```
var weapons = imported_scene.getObjectByName("weapons");
weapons.material = weapons.material.clone();
weapons.material.opacity = 0.5;
weapons.material.transparent = true;
```

See [THREE.Material docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material). three.js r89.

Comment: Also you can capture the texture by reference if you store the texture and reassign it to the clone after cloning. Not how much that saves performance but if it's rather large it could help to not have identical textures using up memory.

Comment: Cloning a material won't clone its textures, see [source code here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.js#L129).

Comment: Oh really? That's interesting. I guess that makes sense since textures are kind of immutable in THREEjs, so it makes sense to just try and save performance by default.